# how to convert left join to sub query?

Tags: mysql

I'm beginner in mysql, i have written a query by using left join to get columns as mentioned in query, i want to convert that query to sub-query please help me out.

```
SELECT b.service_status,
       s.b2b_acpt_flag,
       b2b.b2b_check_in_report,
       b2b.b2b_swap_flag
FROM user_booking_tb AS b
LEFT JOIN b2b.b2b_booking_tbl AS b2b ON b.booking_id=b2b.gb_booking_id
LEFT JOIN b2b.b2b_status AS s ON b2b.b2b_booking_id = s.b2b_booking_id
WHERE b.booking_id='$booking_id'
```

Comment: Why do you want to convert this query?

Comment: Just i want to learn how to convert join to sub-query and more over many records are present it's taking time to fetch records. I want to differentiate speed of sub-query and join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case would actually recommend the join which should generally be quicker as long as you have proper indexes on the joining columns in both tables.

Even with subqueries, you will still want those same joins.

Size and nature of your actual data will affect performance so to know for sure you are best to test both options and measure results. However beware that the optimal query can potentially switch around as your tables grow.

```
SELECT b.service_status,
      (SELECT b2b_acpt_flag FROM b2b_status WHERE b.booking_id=b2b_booking_id)as b2b_acpt_flag,
      (SELECT b2b_check_in_report FROM b2b_booking_tbl  WHERE b.booking_id=gb_booking_id) as b2b_check_in_report,
      (SELECT b2b_check_in_report FROM b2b_booking_tbl  WHERE b.booking_id=gb_booking_id) as b2b_swap_flag
FROM user_booking_tb AS b
WHERE b.booking_id='$booking_id'
```

To dig into how this query works, you are effectively performing 3 additional queries for each and every row returned by the main query.
If b.booking_id='$booking_id' is unique, this is an extra 3 queries, but if there may be multiple entries, this could multiply and become quite slow.

Each of these extra queries will be fast, no network overhead, single row, hopefully matching on a primary key. So 3 extra queries are nominal performance, as long as quantity is low.

A join would result as a single query across 2 indexed tables, which often will shave a few milliseconds off.

Another instance where a subquery may work is where you are filtering the results rather than adding extra columns to output.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM user_booking_tb AS b
WHERE b.booking_id in (SELECT booking_id FROM othertable WHERE this=this and that=that)
```

Depending how large the typical list of booking_id's is will affect which is more efficient.

Comment: Can you please elaborate about execution of both t.he queries i.e about speed any why?

Comment: if i want to add a condition in where clause `WHERE b.booking_id='$booking_id' and b2b_swap_flag!='1' ` i.e the column `b2b_swap_flag` is from `b2b_booking_tbl` then how can i alter the query

Comment: Please help me.